# Plane crash survivors stuck on a creepy island

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

About 20 years ago, I saw part of a film or TV series about a group of people being stranded on a creepy island after a plane crash. I can't remember whether it was a movie or a TV episode, but it felt more like a made-for-TV movie.

The beginning of the movie went like this: a plane is flying through a thunderstorm at night, and there is heavy turbulence. One of the children asks her mother if everything will be all right, and she says they will be. The child then tells her she can't know for sure what will happen, which she acknowledges.

Later, the plane does crash after being hit by lightning, and the survivors manage to reach an island. The survivors explore the island, which is shown to be really creepy. The people then find their food have inexplicably become rotten one morning. That's all I remember.

I searched through [this list](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Robinsonade) on TV Tropes, but none of the movies or TV shows seem to fit the profile. I know it's not *LOST* because I saw this in the 1990s. Does anyone have an idea what this movie (or TV series) might be?

Comment: I remember a show like this called "x-ilse" or "exile". Can't find it in any of the databases though. I've been trying to find this for years.

Comment: I also want this movie .....and yeah it was a series .there was a Chinese people and a black dad with his child and a fat dude with a pregnant women In addition ,the plane crushes next to the Beach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could this be [Danger Island (1992)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104049/reference), also known as The presence?

Plot synopsis from Imdb: "Mixed assortment of people survive the crash of an airliner at sea; cast upon a shore of mysterious island they discover dangerous creatures, exploding bananas, mutations and a biological weapons research facility."

There is a chance you may remember this person from the film, he certainly stuck in my memory as a child:

[image: Guy]

Answer (score 0):

There was a 45 minute show called "The New People" in 1969. It was about a plane crashing on a deserted island that was an abandoned nuke test site. The plane was (an old DC-3) full of young people, and there was a creepy deserted town with test dummy's all over. Could this be it?